# updatepanel cannot work when loading dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, updatepanel

This is the structure of my project.[image]

I want to load the  `QuesEdit.aspx` page into a `div` in the `index.aspx` with `ajax`.

The code in `index.aspx`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadDiv(name) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async:true,
            url: '/index/innerAspx/' + name,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#mainPage").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The trigger event is `<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadDiv('test.aspx');">test</a></li>`

I tried:(in `index.aspx`)

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="mainPage" class="content">
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>`

I also tried to put the `updatepanel` in `QuesEdit.aspx` containing the whole content as [image]

I want to update only the `QuesEdit.aspx` in the `div` when I click a button in `QuesEdit.aspx`. However, it seems like that the postback is sent and the whole page is request to be refreshed. And I got the error message :`http 404`, the request page `/index/QuesEdit.aspx` cannot be found?

why doesn't the updatepanel work?

PS:I want to generate a page like [image]

By click the items on the sidebar, I want to load the corresponding `asp.net` in the mainpage

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange approach - and one with which you will likely have a lot more problems.  Your update panel is working, but you've loaded the content of an entire page inside of it that you're posting back.  I'm not sure why you need to load a page inside a page, but it sounds like you should be using an ascx control for the QuesEdit content - and include your update panel THERE.  Then, you can reference that control from both pages and it'll work.

The reason you're getting the 404 is because you're loading the CONTENT of the QuesEdit.aspx page inside a page in a different directory.  Since you're using relative paths, you're breaking the referential hierarchy by doing that.

Edit:

Example:

QuesEdit.ascx control - in here put your update panel and all of the functionality that you have in your current QuesEdit.aspx page.

QuesEdit.aspx page - in here, load your QuesEdit.ascx control.

index.aspx page - in here, load your QuesEdit.ascx control.  You can toggle its display based on user input if you need to.

Comment: why I need to load a page inside a page is explained above.(I re-edit the question). Is there any better solution to achieve this funciton?